# dnsmasq перенаправление на другой домен

Tags: linux, dns

Как перенаправить один внешний домен на другой внешний(не IP) с помощью dnsmasq?

чтоб **google.com** к примеру вёл на **yandex.ru**

Пробовал так, но что-то не завелось

`server=/google.com/yandex.ru/`

P.S. dnsmasq у меня работает как часть NetworkManager

**Обновлено**

---

ping -a yandex.ua

```
PING yandex.ua (154.47.36.178) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from yandex.ua (154.47.36.178): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=1.08 ms
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
154.47.36.178 yandex.ua

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/local.conf

```
address=/loc/127.0.0.1
cname=google.com,yandex.ua
```

dig google.com

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14335
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     89  IN  A   154.47.36.178

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     5158    IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     5158    IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
google.com.     5158    IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     5158    IN  NS  ns2.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.     4228    IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns1.google.com.     4228    IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::a
ns2.google.com.     4228    IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns2.google.com.     4228    IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:34::a
ns3.google.com.     4228    IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns3.google.com.     4228    IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:36::a
ns4.google.com.     4228    IN  A   216.239.38.10
ns4.google.com.     4228    IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:38::a

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Feb 08 10:40:42 GMT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 303
```

ps aux | grep -i dnsmasq

```
/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --clear-on-reload --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

Comment: Непонятно чего вы этим хотите добиться?

Comment: Это второй вопрос))) Есть легаси проект, который нужно протестировать всем офисом, но для остального мира он должен быть неизменным. Мы думали поднять его на временном домене, но есть еще одна боль, в том что домен захардкожен много где, например в базе и файлах. Это мы тоже будем выпиливать, но не в этой итерации. Поэтому нам нужно чтоб с нашего офиса был доступен тестовый сайт а не живой

Comment: а просто привязать домен на IP не вариант? или у «тестового сервера» он динамический?

Comment: На сервере лежит не один сайт там их сотни.

Comment: @Ninazu, тут DNS не поможет — http (или какие там сайты?) всё равно будет стучаться на сервер с тем hostname'ом, который прописан в приложении... просто сделай, чтобы тестовый web-сервер отвечал на доступ по реальному хостнейму, а в DNS оставь только его ip.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS похоже на то что надо, но умеет ли это dnsmasq я не знаю

Comment: Пропиши в hosts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорей всего единственный вариант — опция `cname`, но на неё накладываются «значительные ограничения»:

> `--cname=<cname>,[<cname>,]<target>[,<TTL>]`
>
> Return a CNAME record which indicates that `<cname>` is really `<target>`. There are significant limitations on the target; it must be a DNS name which is known to dnsmasq from /etc/hosts (or additional hosts files), from DHCP, from `--interface-name` or from another `--cname`...

Вольный перевод:

> Возвращает CNAME запись, что указывает на то, что `<cname>` на самом деле `<target>`. На `<target>` накладываются значительные ограничения: это должно быть DNS имя, известное dnsmasq из `/etc/hosts` (или дополнительных хост-файлов), от DHCP, от  `--interface-name` или от другого `--cname`...

т.е. в `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
cname=google.com,yandex.ru
```

В `/etc/hosts`:

```
77.88.55.66 yandex.ru
```

Но это не то для чего эта опция должна использоваться и может вызвать раздражение у каких-то хитрых приложений.

Простых алиасов/редиректов hostname'ов в `dnsmasq` по факту нет. Причина — это трудно сделать «by-design», пользуйтесь более сложными DNS серверами, подробности расписаны [здесь](http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2006q1/000583.html).

---

Ещё один вариант — модифицировать IP после ответа удалённого сервера:

```
#     ip google.com ,ip yandex.ru
alias=74.125.131.101,77.88.55.66
```

---

См. [`man dnsmasq`](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html)

Comment: Что-то **cname** не сработал, все равно кидает на google.com

Comment: @Ninazu, УМВР, `dig google.com` [до](http://paste.openstack.org/show/744704) и [после](http://paste.openstack.org/show/744705), ищи, что не так настроил... опечатка? забыл про `/etc/hosts`? да, в браузере, конечно, должна быть 406-я ошибка... сервера яндекса пока не настолько самоуверены, чтобы считать себя гуглом...

Comment: УМНН)) Обновил вопрос, добавил лог dig, странно что оно показывает IP яндекса, но через A а не CNAME

Comment: @Ninazu NM `--no-hosts` передаёт, поэтому `/etc/hosts` игнорируется... добавь `addn-hosts=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.hosts` (или какой сочтёшь удобным) и запиши про яндекс туда...

Comment: Большое спасибо)